# EF + POCO Template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I've started using poco templates so that I can generate the pocos for my EF model and copy them to another library.. all this works great however when I need to generate the poco template it needs to be in the same library as my EF model before I can move it to another - this leads to that the generated pocos have the namespace from the library where my EF model is, and when I move the pocos to another library I need to edit each of the pocos' namespace because they are the same as the library with my EF model.

I've used (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/10/poco-template-code-generation-options.aspx)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is how I can transfer the generated poco objects into another library without renaming each of the poco objects namespace afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the generated .tt file I edited the line "string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();" to match the namespace I wanted.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer, if you solved your problem.

Comment: I will.. but I cant untill 21 hours from now :)